# The definition for the morphism of varieties in Hartshorne's book.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

I am reading the Hartshorne's algebraic geometry now, and by his definition for the morphism of varieties:

A continuous map $\varphi:X\to Y$, such that for every open set $V\subseteq Y$ and every regular function $f:Y\to \mathbb{K}$, $f\circ \varphi:\varphi^{-1}(V)\to \mathbb{K}$ is also a regular function.

However, the open set $\varphi^{-1}(V)$ may be empty, then how can we consider the function $f\circ \varphi:\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}$ as a regular function?
If such a function on empty set could be a regular function, why Hartshorne emphasis the open set $\varphi_U^{-1}(V)$ is nonempty when $\langle U,\varphi_U\rangle$ is a dominant rational map? And he also emphasis that $f\circ\varphi_U$ is a regular function on $\varphi_U^{-1}(V)$ because $\varphi_U^{-1}(V)$ is nonempty ($\varphi_U(U)$ is dense in Y).

Comment: I assume that such empty function is a regular function? And I noticed that the definition of the field $K(X)$, for each pairs $<U,\varphi_U>$, open set $U$ should be nonempty.

Comment: It is definitely true that the only function $\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}$ is regular. The empty variety can be described (for instance) as $V(1)\subset \mathbb{A}_n$, and its ring of regular functions is the quotient $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(1)$, which is the zero ring, and obviously consists of the only function $\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you so much! I could understand it now.

Comment: Please use `$\langle U, \varphi_U \rangle$` to produce $\langle U, \varphi_U \rangle$ - greater than and less than signs for this purpose are a typographical nightmare. (Also, note that the condition that a function is regular is given by a "for every point $p$, blah blah blah" so it's vacuously true when there are no points.)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you very much for your advice! I have replace those places, they look better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Captain Lama's answer, empty function $\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}$ is a regular function. However, empty function $\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}$ should not be in the field $K(X)$ of a variety $X$, since if $\langle\emptyset,\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}\rangle$ in the field $K(X)$, then the equivalence relation "$\sim$" on $K(X)$ would not be well-defined:

For two elements $\langle U,\varphi_U\rangle,\langle V,\phi_V\rangle$ in $K(X)$ where $\varphi_U\neq\phi_V$ on $U\cap V$, then we have
$$\langle U,\varphi_U\rangle\sim \langle\emptyset,\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}\rangle \text{ and } \langle\emptyset,\emptyset\to \mathbb{K}\rangle\sim \langle V,\phi_V\rangle, $$
so we could conclude $\langle U,\varphi_U\rangle\sim \langle V,\phi_V\rangle$ which contradicts to $\varphi_U\neq\phi_V$ on $U\cap V$.