# Does birational equivalence between varieties preserves dimensions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I assume that birational equivalence may not preserve dimensions, i.e. if there are two birationally equivalent varieties $X$ and $Y$ (birational maps $\varphi:X\to Y, \langle U,\varphi \rangle$ and $\phi:Y\to X, \langle V,\phi \rangle$ such that $\phi\circ\varphi=id_{\varphi^{-1}(V)},\varphi\circ\phi=id_{\phi^{-1}(U)}$), then $\dim(X)$ and $\dim(Y)$ are not necessarily to be same. However, I could not figure out an appropriate example. I would be really appreciated if someone could figure it out.

Comment: A birational equivalence is an isomorphism of the fields of rational functions, and the dimension is just the trancedence degree of these fields.

Comment: [As before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659575/the-definition-for-the-morphism-of-varieties-in-hartshornes-book#comment9843421_4659575), if you want to use angled brackets, please use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` - greater-than and less-than signs do not render well for this purpose.

Comment: Another way to understand that dimension is preserved under birationality is that the dimension of a (irreducible) variety is the dimension of any nonempty open subset, and if $X, Y$ are birational to each other, then by definition they have nonempty open subsets that are homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you so much! I missed the property of dimension, when I considered this question.

Comment: @CJDowd Thank you very much, too! You let me review this claim by geometric version.